# Changes to using a lightbox

Tags: fancybox, thumbnails, lightbox

On my website I'm using Fancy Gallery on multiple pages for the images, when a thumbnail is clicked it's currently viewing the images in lightbox 'FancyBox'. For one of the pages, I'm wanting, when a thumbnail is clicked to link directly to a different page or existing blog post, what would be the best way going about this?

Thanks